# Elastic search : get count of few fields data

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

```
[
{"Exam" : "mid-term 1", "Name": "abc", "Roll no" : "1" , "English" :"Pass", "Hindi" :"Pass" , "Physics" : "Not available", "Maths": "Fail"},
{"Exam" : "mid-term 2", "Name": "abc", "Roll no" : "1" , "English" :"Fail", "Hindi" :"Pass" , "Physics" : "Fail", "Maths": "result awaiting"},
{"Exam" : "mid-term 3", "Name": "abc", "Roll no" : "1" , "English" :"Pass", "Hindi" :"Fail" , "Physics" : "Pass", "Maths": "Pass"},

{"Exam" : "mid-term 1", "Name": "cde", "Roll no" : "2" , "English" :"Pass", "Hindi" :"Pass" , "Physics" : "Pass", "Maths": "Pass"},
{"Exam" : "mid-term 2", "Name": "cde", "Roll no" : "2" , "English" :"Pass", "Hindi" :"Pass" , "Physics" : "Pass", "Maths": "Pass"},
{"Exam" : "mid-term 3", "Name": "cde", "Roll no" : "2" , "English" :"Pass", "Hindi" :"Pass" , "Physics" : "Pass", "Maths": "Pass"},

{"Exam" : "mid-term 1", "Name": "xyz", "Roll no" : "3" , "English" :"Pass", "Hindi" :"Pass" , "Physics" : "Pass", "Maths": "Pass"},
{"Exam" : "mid-term 2", "Name": "xyz", "Roll no" : "3" , "English" :"result awaiting", "Hindi" :"Fail" , "Physics" : "Fail", "Maths": "Pass"},
{"Exam" : "mid-term 3", "Name": "xyz", "Roll no" : "3" , "English" :"Pass", "Hindi" :"Pass" , "Physics" : "Fail", "Maths": "Fail"},

{"Exam" : "mid-term 1", "Name": "zxc", "Roll no" : "4" , "English" :"Not available", "Hindi" :"result awaiting" , "Physics" : "Fail", "Maths": "Pass"},
{"Exam" : "mid-term 2", "Name": "zxc", "Roll no" : "4" , "English" :"Not available", "Hindi" :"Pass" , "Physics" : "Pass", "Maths": "Fail"},
{"Exam" : "mid-term 3", "Name": "zxc", "Roll no" : "4" , "English" :"Not available", "Hindi" :"Pass" , "Physics" : "Pass", "Maths": "Pass"},
]
```

assume we have a data like above, three different exam data for a student with there name and Rollno and subject pass, fail/Not available(like not attempted), result awaiting

Now we need count of different fields on basis like   physics fail
so ROll no 1,2,4 got failed in physics exams (failed in any exam , mid-term 1 / 2 /3)
so if we fetch data by physics fail
it will be like below

```
{"Exam" : "mid-term 3", "Name": "abc", "Roll no" : "1" , "English" :"Pass", "Hindi" :"Fail" , "Physics" : "Pass", "Maths": "Pass"},

{"Exam" : "mid-term 2", "Name": "xyz", "Roll no" : "3" , "English" :"Pass", "Hindi" :"Fail" , "Physics" : "Fail", "Maths": "Pass"},
{"Exam" : "mid-term 3", "Name": "xyz", "Roll no" : "3" , "English" :"Pass", "Hindi" :"Pass" , "Physics" : "Fail", "Maths": "Fail"},

{"Exam" : "mid-term 1", "Name": "zxc", "Roll no" : "4" , "English" :"Not available", "Hindi" :"result awaiting" , "Physics" : "Fail", "Maths": "Pass"},
```

but I dont want for a student data should be repeated only singly data (irrespective of exam )

Like data below

```
{"Exam" : "mid-term 3", "Name": "abc", "Roll no" : "1" , "English" :"Pass", "Hindi" :"Fail" , "Physics" : "Pass", "Maths": "Pass"},

{"Exam" : "mid-term 2", "Name": "xyz", "Roll no" : "3" , "English" :"Pass", "Hindi" :"Fail" , "Physics" : "Fail", "Maths": "Pass"},

{"Exam" : "mid-term 1", "Name": "zxc", "Roll no" : "4" , "English" :"Not available", "Hindi" :"result awaiting" , "Physics" : "Fail", "Maths": "Pass"},
```

Now I want  count of data

```
English : 2 ( roll 1 annd 3 was pass , not condidered roll no 4 english due to Not available")

Hindi : 0 (no pass)
Physics: 1
Maths: 3
```

can we achieve this count in single ES query?

Answer (score 0):

yeah use term aggregation on the subjects

```
{
  "aggs":{
    "english":{
      "terms": { "field": "english" }
    },
     "physics":{
      "terms": { "field": "physics" }
    },
     "hindi":{
      "terms": { "field": "hindi" }
    }
  }
}
```

the result will be something like this

````
  "aggs": {
    "english": [
      {
        "Pass": {
          "doc_count": 2
        }
      },
      {
        "Fail": {
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      },
      {
        "Not Available": {
          "doc_count": 3
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}```
````

Comment: I do not want data from all document , how we can filter to get only 1 result for roll no. 3 
to get unique

Comment: use filter in the query or use filter aggregation

Comment: but how  to handle that case , that roll no 3 data should not be repeated

Comment: apply cardinality aggregation on roll no inside term aggregation of the subject which will give the unique count.
is it what you are expecting?